# Sql server reporting service not showing report data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I created a report project in sql server business intelligence developement studio and deployed successfully with sql reporting service url(Webservice url).It work fine but when i browsing my  report application through reporting service url and result like this.

This  first image  report service deployed successfully

[image]

when i click report just loading but no report 
data

Comment: Use profiler to verify the report is sending the right query to the right server/database.

Comment: Have you check if the `Datasource` information is correct on the server?

Comment: my second report not related database.Just some text boxes with static datas.No relation database connection .report icon are displayed but datas are not displayed.When i debug from business intelligence development studio ,it works

Comment: yes , I got answer by unclicking excution Account in Report server. Thanks for all

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using **IE**?

I think you need **Javascript** enabled and maybe something else to make SSRS Report Manager work with **Chrome**.

Apparently other browsers have compatibility issues:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156511.aspx

There is also **IE Tab for Chrome** to fix some issues:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd?hl=en-US

Comment: thank you, Got answer by uncliking excution account in report server

Comment: and also add IE tab into chrome

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix for this problem, and if you are browsing using Chrome, you can add the IE Tab in the settings, extensions for chrome and it will render the report as it loads a version of IE and the Report Server will allow the report data to load.